# Python 2.5 Import dll AttributeError

Tags: dllimport, python-2.5, attributeerror

I have a program that runs peachy in Py2.4. I import the TobiiPlugin.dll file and then run my scripts.

```
import TobiiPlugin as tobii
tobii.setGazeSubjectProfile(3, 0)
```

However, when I moved the code to Py2.5 it gets angry at me and I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\tobiiDll\TobiiPlugin\Debug\logger_speech.py", line 274, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\tobiiDll\TobiiPlugin\Debug\logger_speech.py", line 242, in main
    tobii.setGazeSubjectProfile(3, 0)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 325, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 330, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: function 'setGazeSubjectProfile' not found
>>>
```

How did everything manage to go missing? It's not just this function either. I tried others from the DLL and they didn't work either. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the [Tobii SDK 3.0 Beta](http://landningpages.tobii.com/landingpads/analysis_sdk_beta.aspx) only works with Python 2.4 or Python 2.6.